# iOS - Subview frame size inherited from parent view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uicontainerview

I'm trying to set up a view inside a container view. It has to be done this way due to several different controllers for the views inside the `swipeView`.

```
@IBOutlet weak var containerView: ContainerView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

     //Some other stuff

     //Create new swipeView
     var swipeView = MDCSwipeToChooseView(frame: containerView.frame, options: options)

    //Add the view from the controller to the swipeView
    swipeView.addSubview(containerViewController.view)

    //Add the swipeView to the main view
    self.view.addSubview(swipeView)
```

I end up with this

[image]

The white area is the view that should inherit `containerView`'s size. The `containerView` is the pink one in the background and it's shown properly. I have noticed that `containerView.frame` returns the size of the component from the storyboard, see pic 2. The frame obtained by calling on the `containerView.frame` is the one before the view is resized to meet all constrains. How do i get the proper values?

[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Placing the same code inside `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` instead of `viewDidLoad()` solved the issue.

Comment: It would probably work in `viewDidLoad` too if you set each view's `autoresizingMask` properly.